# Overwrite previous output/buffer

Tags: php

I have a for loop which runs a certain amount of times and outputs something each times it runs. I would like to overwrite or replace the previous echo's/outputs.

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo "Number" . $i . " \r";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

This will output something like this:

```
Number0 Number1 Number2 Number3 Number4 Number5
```

What I like to get is `Number: X` where X will be updated/replaced every time the loop runs.

I've tried a few methods but I'm not making any progress on this by myself. Any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: what about JS? shouldn't you be making this on that layer instead? there's a `setInterval` there that you could use

Comment: @Kevin To explain it a bit further, my real task is to output the percentage of a local copy task. I use php to get the src directory size and then calculate the percentage of how much have been copied to the dst directory. So you're saying the best way would be to use javascript for fetching the php output? Sry if I miss understood you.

Comment: you could just use that PHP to return the percentage alone, then use javascript and request via xmlhttrequest (ajax) to query that percentage, then output it on the browser

Comment: `\r` will only work for a console-script (php-cli). Are you testing your script in a browser?

Comment: @Pilan I guess that's my problem then. Yes it's being executed in a browser. Kevins suggestion sounds good, I just need to wrap my head around how to fetch a var from within a php while loop via ajax.

Comment: @Florian since I have not tried getting the percentage / progress of copying a file in PHP, so i can't help you with that, but if you already have a solution on getting the number on each request, then it's just trivial after that, just use `setInterval` use ajax, then just simply echo the number, it's just a matter of using the response after that

Comment: here's a fiddle and use it as a starting point. https://www.tehplayground.com/ymi1iUjqkISBC5p7 create a `test.php` or something and run it. it's basically just a simple ajax calling itself every one second. i just made a simple mechanism similar to a progress so that at least it simulates a number increasing every request. it stops after it completes 100%. if you already have the copy progress number, then just simply replace the php in there

Comment: @Kevin Thanks so much for fiddle. I had a play the last hour or so and I do understand how this works now. But I do have one more question if you don't mind. Right now the ajax.responseText contains the entire DOM, which means if you have divs or navs before the **percent element** that get's inserted as well. How can I tell it to only use **$_POST['percentage']**?

Comment: @Florian you could either put the php part on a separate file so that it outputs a lone number that you need for updating (the response) or optionally just echo a json encoded response `echo json_encode(['response' => number here]);`. or put an `exit` on the end. `echo $_POST['percentage']; exit;` so that it doesn't output the rest of the dom. i'd prefer the separate php route though. i just put everything on one fiddle together for example's sake

Comment: @Kevin I gave it another go today and I think my javascript code is right, but for some reason I still receive all the dom when I request json via ajax. I've uploaded everything into a fiddle with my code commented. It probably comes down to a small mistake I bet.. https://www.tehplayground.com/nQqE29lSVYq38eMi

Comment: I finally got what you meant by moving the code into a seperate php file and then call only that file via ajax. Thanks so much for your help @Kevin!

Comment: sure glad this helped